# How to multiupload in Form of TYPO3 v12.4.6?

Tags: typo3, slack, typo3-12.x

When I select multiple files and send the form (then result gets send by mail) the Mail contains everything but uploads. When switching back to single-upload-version everything works but just with one picture.

Is there someone who can help me with that? What do I have to do to make form processing the images/uploads when I have multiple of them?

Is there any solution for this